# How can I change the background color of a header from a TListView?

Tags: listview, delphi, header, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin

I need change the background color of all header of my listView for them to be highlighted. I found nothing on Object Inspector and nothing on Style Designer, can you guys give me some direction?

[image]

Comment: This does not seem to be doable with the object inspector. I suggest you try with the StyleDesigner... modifying the listboxstyle \ listboxplainheader \ background. I'm not sure about this, but I seem to recall that the ListView uses the listbox styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one, it worked for me. You can delete the Rectangle component.

- right click the LV
- edit custom style
- select header
- click on SourceLink property (...)
- there you can either chose one of the existing colors, or create your own
- close the BitmapLinks Editor
- Close and save the Style Designer
  Should work

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to place a Rectangle component inside the header item of your LV (ListView), then change its color accordingly. Here is how to accomplish it:

- Your LV must be in Dynamic Appearance (I believe it already is)
- Right click on you LV, and select Edit Custom Style
- In the Style Container->expand your LV->expand Header
- Drag a Rectangle component onto your LV header (MAKE SURE IT IS INSIDE THE HEADER item).
- Set the desired fill color for the Rectangle.
- Set its alignment to client
- Close and save your Style Designer.

Should be working now

Comment: You can also apply some effects to it such as shadows, etc.

Comment: At the step four, the Header should be parent of the Rectangle? If yes, didn't worked...